# Win2003 R2 - 1.5TB disks not identified

Tags: windows-server-2003, hard-drive, sata

I just installed 4 1.5TB hard disks (WD) in two servers (2 in each). Upon reboot they are not showing up in the disk manager whatsoever.

I'm running Windows Server 2003 EE (32bit) with 8GB ram. They both currently have mirrored 300GB sata disks. Why aren't they being recognized? Is there a disk size limit for win2k3 r2?

Comment: Are they being recognized in the machine's BIOS?

Comment: Do you have a RAID array that could be causing issues? What type of physical machine is this? Specs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, this was actually the result of sata cables between the controller and the mainboard not being fully connected. Upon closer inspection the cables were resting against the inputs but weren't actually connected. Thank you both for your help.